# iOS 9: Background Image for UINavigationBar not working

Tags: background, uiimage, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a global background image (basically some orange color) which is set for all navigation bars inside the AppDelegate:

```c
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"order-navbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This works for all views except one: I have an MFMailComposeViewController whose navigation bar background stays white-gray no matter what I do:

```c
let mailController = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // this works
emailController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "order-navbar") forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default) // this does not
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "order-navbar") forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default) // this does neither
```

However, sometimes the mail controller appears at first with the orange bar and then suddenly changes its color to white-gray again.

On iOS 8 everything works. Is this an iOS 9 bug?

Comment: did you get any solution?